# VirtualBox FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted. after resize

Tags: boot, virtualbox, vhd

After resizing VHD file with

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "c:\VMs\WinXP.vhd" --resize 50000
```

and successful operation I cannot boot from this VHD:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

Previous size was 29.9 GB. Host is Win7, guest on this VHD is WinXP.

When I run VirtualBox VM with linux live and GParted the VHD, it shows 50GB of unallocated space.
On the other side, when I run linux live on Virtual PC and GParted VHD, it shows 7.9GB of unallocated space.

I have tried recovery by Gparted, no partitions found.
I have tried recovery console from WinXP installation (fixmbr...) nothing changes.

I have also tried everything from [Cannot boot after vhd hard drive is resized in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/422527/cannot-boot-after-vhd-hard-drive-is-resized-in-virtualbox)

I have a backup of VHD, but it's few months old, and I'd hate to do everything again (it was my DEV station).

What should I do?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. I have not been able to locate a solution to this as of this post. Keep an eye on https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=59561.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the instructions in many blogs are very confusing. The simple thing at my end was to go into repair mode and use diskpart to set the smaller virtualbox partition as active and boot. That partition is typically like a 100MB.